# Get current value from a SQL Server SEQUENCE

Tags: t-sql, sequence, sql-server-2012

I want to get the current value from my sequence - the same value that is shown in the sequence properties window SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

My sequence is created with this statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [OrderNumberSequence]
    as int
    START WITH 4000
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 0
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO CACHE;
GO
```

I have tried this [SQL from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878352.aspx) – but the result is that my number is increasing with 5 for every time I run the query

```
DECLARE  
  @FirstSeqNum sql_variant
, @LastSeqNum sql_variant
, @CycleCount int
, @SeqIncr sql_variant
, @SeqMinVal sql_variant
, @SeqMaxVal sql_variant ;

EXEC sys.sp_sequence_get_range
@sequence_name = N'[OrderNumberSequence]'
, @range_size = 5
, @range_first_value = @FirstSeqNum OUTPUT 
, @range_last_value = @LastSeqNum OUTPUT 
, @range_cycle_count = @CycleCount OUTPUT
, @sequence_increment = @SeqIncr OUTPUT
, @sequence_min_value = @SeqMinVal OUTPUT
, @sequence_max_value = @SeqMaxVal OUTPUT ;

-- The following statement returns the output values
SELECT
  @FirstSeqNum AS FirstVal
, @LastSeqNum AS LastVal
, @CycleCount AS CycleCount
, @SeqIncr AS SeqIncrement
, @SeqMinVal AS MinSeq
, @SeqMaxVal AS MaxSeq ;
```

Is there a way that I can get the value without changing the number?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can select the  `current_value` from `sys.sequences`:

```
SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'OrderNumberSequence' ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f59b/1/0)

Comment: I tried to store the value of `current_value` in a variable I created with `DECLARE` only to find out `current_value` is of type `sql_variant`. That came as a surprise. I expected/needed an `int` or `bigint` and had to use `CONVERT`.

Comment: For those who were wondering what @BernhardDöbler was saying, the syntax is `SELECT CAST(current_value AS int) FROM sys.sequences ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, but if you are on SQL2017+ and wondering how to get the correct value for a sequence, even when no value at all has been taken from it, you should take into account column `last_value_used` too.
When the sequence has been created for the first time, the simple statement `SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'OrderNumberSequence' ;` will return the first value that the sequence will be returning after the first `next value from ..`. Then, after the first `next value from`, that statement will return the same result!

Instead, it would be better to have `NULL` when no value has ever been taken from the sequence, e.g. when the sequence has just been created or restarted.

Table `sys.sequences` has a `last_value_used` column that is `NULL` when no value has been taken from the sequence or the sequence has just been restarted.
In other words, while `current_value` column reports the first value that will be using the sequence on first "`next value from`" and from that point on will be reporting the "current actual value", column `last_value_used` will be `NULL` until you ask for the first value.
From that point on, `last_value_used` will be always equal to `current_value`.

You can use sample snippet down here to test it by yourself.

```
drop sequence if exists dbo.MySequence
go

-- 1. create sequence without touching it
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[MySequence] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 2147483647
 CYCLE 
 CACHE 
GO

-- 2. observe current_value and last_used_value columns (should be current_value = 1, last_used_value = null)
SELECT 'Observe initial state of sequence after creation' msg, current_value, last_used_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'MySequence'

-- 3. get current value of sequence, based on last_used_value nullable state
declare @CurrentValue sql_variant
SELECT @CurrentValue = CASE WHEN last_used_value IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE current_value END
FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'MySequence'

select 'Current actual value' msg, @CurrentValue current_value -- should be null

-- 4. get next value from sequence
select 'Get first value from sequence' msg, next value for dbo.MySequence value -- should be 1

-- 5. observe current_value and last_used_value columns (should be current_value = 1, last_used_value = 1)
SELECT 'Observe state of sequence after getting first value' msg, current_value, last_used_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'MySequence'

-- 6. get current value of sequence, based on last_used_value nullable state
SELECT @CurrentValue = CASE WHEN last_used_value IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE current_value END
FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'MySequence'

select 'Current actual value' msg, @CurrentValue current_value -- should be 1

-- 7. get another value from seqeunce
select 'Get second value from sequence' msg, next value for dbo.MySequence value -- should be 2

-- 8. observe current_value and last_used_value columns (should be current_value = 2, last_used_value = 2)
SELECT 'Observe state of sequence after getting second value' msg, current_value, last_used_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'MySequence'

-- 9. get current value of sequence, based on last_used_value nullable state
SELECT @CurrentValue = CASE WHEN last_used_value IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE current_value END
FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'MySequence'

select 'Current actual value' msg, @CurrentValue current_value -- should be 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can use this:

```
SELECT last_value FROM <sequence_name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

For T-Sql, you can create a function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCurrentSequenceValue](@seqName as varchar(50)) RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- potentially you can remove unwanted dbo or [] characters or modify sequence name here
    SET @seqName = Replace(Replace(Replace(@seqName,'[',''), ']',''),'dbo.','');
    RETURN convert(varchar(max),(select current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name=@seqName));
END
```

Comment: Okay, but outside of wrapping this in a function, how does this compare to the well-established answers previously posted? Are you doing anything different, or just wrapping this in a function. (Which, I should note, wasn’t what the question is about.)